# How to get a list of all available servlets?

Tags: java, servlets

Is it possible to get a list of all available servlets in an app?

I'm writing a web application that will expose a lot of servlets and I want to use HttpUnit to test each one to see if it is returning (or not!).

As lot of it will return a simple XML response, it would be really helpful not to write a test case for each one, only verify that it is working (a database change has not stopped this servlet to work, for example).

Comment: I'm not aware of a function to do it, but the app's web.xml will have a list of all of them.

Answer (score 11):

```
Map<String, ? extends ServletRegistration> servletRegistrations = request.getServletContext().getServletRegistrations();
```

It will help you.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. But FYI to others, the `getServletRegistrations()` method  is only available since Servlet 3.0 specification (i.e. Java EE 6 - i.e. Tomcat 7+)

Answer (score 1):

Don't think there is something out of the box. However you could write a small programm which parses your web.xml to gain the needed information.

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection you can look for all classes that are a HTTPServlet.

Comment: I don't think you can use reflection to see implementations of HTTPServlet. I know that it's not possible to get instances of a class/interface as the class loaded doesn't know about them until they're loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you use tomcat, you can include the server jars in your classpath, and then cast the ServletContext to the Tomcat implementation. It contains everything you need.

Comment: As of tomcat 5.5, it is not available. Both getServletNames() and getServlets() are deprecated, with no replacement, and always return an empty enumeration. See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getServlets()

Comment: You cannot use the public APIs, just the internal APIs. This is why I saif "include the server jars", that jars in $TOMCAT_HOME/server/lib