# The `getServletNames()` method returns empty, how do I get the actual list/enumeration?

Tags: java, spring-boot

The `getBeanDefinitionNames()` method returns a list of beans. Similarly, I'm trying to get a list of `Servlet`s.

Here is the code

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    ServletContext context; 

    @GetMapping
    int home(){
        Enumeration<String> servletNames = context.getServletNames();
        while (servletNames.hasMoreElements()) {
          String servletName = servletNames.nextElement();
            System.out.println(servletName);
        }
        return 200;
    }
}
```

However, the above code gets me nothing, as the doc says

> this method always returns an empty Enumeration

How do I get the actual list/enumeration?

Env: spring boot 2.7.7 + jdk 1.8.0_352

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4037458/1553851) help?